flask celery throw error "urls must start with a leading slash"
I'm trying to implement the celery using flask and when i run this command celery -A src.celery_worker.celery_app worker --loglevel=debug to start the celery worker, it throwing error:

Couldn't import 'src.celery_worker.celery_app': urls must start with a
leading slash

Here's the full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 58, in convert
    return find_app(value)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 383, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 61, in symbol_by_name
    reraise(ValueError,
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 59, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 109, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/src/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    api = Api(
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 236, in init_app
    self._init_app(app)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 247, in _init_app
    self._register_doc(self.blueprint or app)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 320, in _register_doc
    app_or_blueprint.add_url_rule(self._doc, "doc", self.render_doc)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 56, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1083, in add_url_rule
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
  File "/home/sonnc/project/mac/lifescience-operator-management-bff/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 698, in __init__
    raise ValueError("urls must start with a leading slash")
ValueError: Couldn't import 'src.celery_worker.celery_app': urls must start with a leading slash

Below is the file src/celery_worker/__init__.py:
import os
from flask import Flask

from celery import Celery, Task


def celery_init_app(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app


def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # url for local redis
    # redis_url = "redis://localhost:6379"
    # url for docker redis
    # redis_url = "redis://redis:6379/0"
    app.config.from_mapping(
        CELERY=dict(
            broker_url="redis://localhost:6379",
            result_backend="redis://localhost:6379",
            task_ignore_result=True,
            # import the tasks
            # imports=("src.common.send_email",),
        ),
    )
    app.config.from_prefixed_env()
    celery_init_app(app)
    return app


flask_app = create_app()
celery_app = flask_app.extensions["celery"]

Look like the error is related to the flask_restx module, but I can't trace how it causing this issue.
Please help, thanks.

EDIT 1:
Here's the proof that every route and path in my source code are start with a slash:



This error is usually caused by a bad route. But you did not include any in your code.

@KlausD. hi, may i know what's the bad route as you say? the project is a company project so I can't post in here, but if you know anything or anyhow to trace the issue, please tell me, thanks.

If you can not post the code to reproduce the problem due to copyright reasons, Stack Overflow is not the right place for your problem. In general a "route" in this context is a Werkzeug (as used by many project like Flask) route(path, ...) decorator. The path in there has to start with a slash.

@KlausD. I can make sure that every route or path in the code starts with a slash. Do you have any other ideas?

Stack Onerflow is not about ideas, you have to produce a minimal reproducible example.

error shows problem with src.celery_worker.celery_app - so maybe first use print() to see what you have in celery_app in file celery_worker.py. You could also use print() to see which part of code is executed.

@furas thanks, i'll try that and feedback to you on monday.

@furas sorry for disappointing you, I've tried to add print(celery_app) and other print() in the start of the code as well but looks like it doesn't print anything.

maybe you have to use print() in other places - to see if they run correctly and if you have correct values in variables.

Thanks you all for your answers and suggestions, I've tried to debug the next day but somehow it suddenly worked on the local environment, the issue is gone, I don't really understand why, but the issue still remains on the docker environment.
So I've tried to debug further and found that the reason it's because the setting in docker-compose.yml didn't set the env_file file.
So I added the env_file to the setting of celery_worker in docker-compose.yml and it worked, here's how I fixed it:
celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/celery_worker/Dockerfile
    image: flask_celery_worker
    command: 
      ["/start-celeryworker", "sh", "-c"]
      # ['celery', '-A', 'src.celery_worker.celery_app', 'worker', '-l', 'debug']
      # celery -A src.celery_worker.celery_app worker --loglevel=debug
    # volumes:
    #   - .:/lifescience-operator-management-bff-worker
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 6900:6900
    networks:
      - my-network
    # environment:
    #   - FLASK_APP=app
    depends_on:
      - redis

Well, I know it sounds like doesn't related to the issue that I've posted, but believe me, that's all I did to fix this issue.
 Hope this answer help some one.

This is the error:

ValueError: Couldn't import 'src.celery_worker.celery_app': urls must start with a leading slash

Which tells you that you will need to prepend a leading slash of / to the route, resulting in /yourroute
Make sure all your routes start with a slash, like
@app.route('/foo/bar/')


thanks for the answer, I can make sure that every route or path in my source code starts with a slash, so it shouldn't be the problem. do you have any other ideas?

@fudu no, that must be the problem. The error message makes is very clear. So, maybe some route was missed.

Not to be rude, but I've added the proof on the EDIT part in my question, please check.

@fudu I understand your point, but the error message is still claiming that you have a url without a starting slash. I would advise you to debug the app around the locations shared in the stack trace.
